# How to use a different version of Npm and Cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

We have downloaded and installed a different `Npm` instance outside Visual Studio on our development machine and set the system classpath to use this version;
using this Npm, we have downloaded the latest version of Cordova (3.5.0).

Apparently, it seems that Visual Studio 2013 is using this new `Npm` installation and Cordova version when building; using this configuration we can correctly build and deploy to WP8, Android and iOS.
Also the plugins (enabled from the `config.xml` in VS) are downloaded and set in the new Cordova path.

Looking at the build log, I've however noticed that the iOS build is reporting that the 3.4.0 version of Cordova is used.

Is this kind of configuration supported?
Which is the correct way to use a different version of Cordova?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update Multi-Device Hybrid Apps to the CTP2, Visual Studio now uses Cordova 3.5.0 instead of 3.4.1. You should also update your instance of vs-mda-remote on your Mac to stay in sync for iOS.

There is currently not a supported way to select a version of Cordova though that is on the roadmap.